# Annulus without ambient space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

An annulus $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1<x^2+y^2 < 2\}$ is a topological subspace of 2-D Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$ and has a boundary composed of two components. But if we forget $\mathbb{R}^2 - A$ completely (so the whole universe is $A$ itself), then it clearly has no boundary. This space should be topologically different from $A$. However, in terms of loops (I just started studying elementary algebraic topology), the two spaces seems to be equivalent. Intuitively the two spaces have the same classes of continuously deformable loops. With what algebraic topological tool can I distinguish the two spaces?

Comment: What is the boundary of $A$ as a subsapce of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @ODF The circles of radius 1 and $\sqrt{2}$ form the boundary. So?

Comment: Because your annulus is open the boundary isn't a part of $A$ - $A$ has no boundary

Comment: @ODF Does it matter? A subset and its closure have the same boundary. Moreover the boundary changes if we change the topology endowed to the subset.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're comparing. $A$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ versus $A$ as a subspace of itself? It's the same space both times, you're just embedding it in different spaces.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't matter - however you can use much more straightforward topological tools to distinguish them. As a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $A$'s closure is strictly larger than $A$, whereas the closure of $A$ considered as a space on its own is $A$.

Comment: @ODF Yes, so the two are topologically different. My question is algebraic topological tools available to distinguish the two.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I think different boundaries for the same set implies different topologies. Am I right? Actually I'm not so confident as my study on topology is so short. If I'm right, the annulus without the ambient space must have a topology different from the relative topology.

Comment: No. The boundary of a set depends on the embedding (i.e. it depends on the surrounding space), not on the topology of the set itself. So the annulus does in fact have the same topology no matter what space it's embedded in.

Comment: Other spaces that have the same topology as the annulus include the plane with a point removed, the sphere with two points removed, and the curved face of a cylinder.

Comment: Usually when topologists informally speak about two topological spaces being the "same" or "different", they are referring to the equivalence relation of "homeomorphism". You have said that "This space should be topologically different from $A$", and yet the two spaces are homeomorphic. Do you have some other equivalence relation in mind than homeomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "loops" will not detect something as subtle as you mean. However, it is also true that taking the closure of an open subset and considering the boundary of the resulting space depends on how you embed a space.

For example the subsets $\{(x,y,z) \mid z \neq \pm 1\} \subset S^2$ is topologically a cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb R$ which is homeomorphic to the open annulus. Likewise, you can consider $\{(x,y,z) \mid |z|<1/2\}$ is also an annulus. The "boundary" of the first is two points and the boundary of the latter is $S^1 \coprod S^1$, despite them being homeomorphic.

On the other hand "loops" will only detect up to homotopy. For example, as a space unto itself, $S^1$ and $S^1 \times \mathbb R$ will have the same fundamental group.